# Getting only Sub Elements

Tags: mongodb

If I have the following document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54986d5531a011bb5fb8e0ee"),
    "owner" : "54948a5d85f7a9527a002917",
    "type" : "group",
    "deleted" : false,
    "participants" : [
        { "_id": "54948a5d85f7a9527a002917", "name": "user1" },
        { "_id": "5491234568f7a9527a002918", "name": "user2" },
        { "_id": "5491234568f7a9527a002918", "name": "user3" },
        { "_id": "1234567aaaa7a9527a002917", "name": "user2" }
    ]
}
```

How would I get all records where name = 'user2'?

I'm trying the followoing:

```
db.users.find({ _id: ObjectId('54a7103b1a57eee00bc0a9e4') }, 
{ 'participants.$.name': 'user2') }).pretty()
```

...and I get the following:

```
error: {
    "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Positional projection 'participants.$.name' does not match the query document.",
    "code" : 17287
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the positional operator([$](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)) would give you the first matching element from the participant array. If you need all  the participants in with the name `user2`, you need to aggregate the results.

- `Match` the document with the required `_id`.
- Use the [redact](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) operator to only keep all the sub documents that have
  participants, who have their name as `user2`.

Code:

```
var search = "user2";
db.users.aggregate([
{$match:{"_id":ObjectId("54986d5531a011bb5fb8e0ee")}},
{$redact:{$cond:[{$eq:[{$ifNull:["$name",search]},search]},
                 "$$DESCEND",
                 "$$PRUNE"]}},
{$project:{"participants":1,"_id":0}} // set _id:1, if you need the _id.
])
```

o/p:

```
{
        "participants" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "5491234568f7a9527a002918",
                        "name" : "user2"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "1234567aaaa7a9527a002917",
                        "name" : "user2"
                }
        ]
}
```

Coming to your query,

```
db.users.find({ _id: ObjectId('54a7103b1a57eee00bc0a9e4') }, 
              { 'participants.$.name': 'user2'}).pretty()
```

The positional operator can be applied only on the array, that is referred in the query document of the find function. The above query document doesn't have a reference to the array named `participants` and only refers to the `_id` field to match a document. Hence you get the error.

From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/),

> The  field being limited must appear in the query document

So, changing the query to include the participants array in the query document would fix the error.

```
  db.users.find({ "_id":ObjectId('54a7103b1a57eee00bc0a9e4'),
                  "participants.name": "user2"
                }, 
                {"participants.$.name":"user2"}).pretty()
```

But it would return you only the first participant that has matched the criteria in the query document.

From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/),

> Use $ in the projection document of the find() method or the findOne()
>   method when you only need one particular array element in selected
>   documents.

o/p:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54986d5531a011bb5fb8e0ee"),
        "participants" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "5491234568f7a9527a002918",
                        "name" : "user2"
                }
        ]
}
```